# Add data labels to spineplot in R

Tags: r, plot, label

```
iFacColName <- "hireMonth"

iTargetColName <- "attrition"

iFacVector <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,12,9,9,1,10,12,1,9,5))

iTargetVector <- as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1))

sp <- spineplot(iFacVector,iTargetVector,xlab=iFacColName,ylab=iTargetColName,main=paste0(iFacColName," vs. ",iTargetColName," Spineplot"))
spLabelPass <- sp[,2]/(sp[,1]+sp[,2])
spLabelFail <- 1-spLabelPass
text(seq_len(nrow(sp)),rep(.95,length(spLabelPass)),labels=as.character(spLabelPass),cex=.8)
```

For some reason, the `text()` function only plots one label far to the right of the graph.  I have used this format to apply data labels to other types of graphs, so I am confused.

EDIT:  added more code to make example work

Comment: What are iFacColName and iTargetColName?

Comment: Sorry, edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not placing your labels inside the plotting region. It only extends to around 1.3 on the x axis. Try plotting something like

```
text(
  cumsum(prop.table(table(iFacVector))),
  rep(.95, length(spLabelPass)),
  labels = as.character(round(spLabelPass, 1)),
  cex = .8
)
```

and you'll get something like

[image]

This is obviously not the right positions for the labels, but you should be able to figure that out by yourself. (You're going to have to subtract half of the frequency for each bar from the cumulative frequency and account for the fact that the bars are padded with some amount of whitespace.