# How can I plot data labels over spineplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a spineplot in R from a table. I would like to add data labels with counts inside each of the bars. As far as I can tell from the docs, this is not an argument that I can pass with the 'spineplot' function. Below I include a screenshot of my current plot and an example of what I would like to achieve below it - you can see that the latter has text over the bars. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

My code:

```
spineplot(table(myData$BP_cluster,myData$DP_dispersion_quartile),
      col = c("green","blue","orange","purple","yellow"),
      xlab="cluster",
      ylab="DP_measure_quartile",
      off = 0)
```

[image: my current plot]

[image: what I would like to achieve]

[image]

Comment: See this related post to add text: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42982088/680068

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way:

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$hp_fac <- cut(mtcars$hp, breaks=3)
tab <- table(mtcars$hp_fac, mtcars$am)
nums <- t(apply(tab, 1,rev))
pcts <- prop.table(cbind(0, nums), 1)
pcts <- t(apply(pcts, 1, cumsum))
yvals <- pcts[,-ncol(pcts)] + (pcts[,-1] - pcts[,-ncol(pcts)])/2
xvals <- cumsum(c(0, rowSums(nums)/sum(rowSums(nums))))
xvals <- xvals[-length(xvals)] + (xvals[-1] - xvals[-length(xvals)])/2
xvals <- array(xvals, dim=dim(yvals))
xvals <- c(xvals)
yvals <- c(yvals)
labs <- sprintf("n = %.0f", c(nums))

spineplot(tab,
          col = c("green","blue","orange","purple","yellow"),
          xlab="cluster",
          ylab="DP_measure_quartile",
          off = 0)

text(x=xvals, y=yvals, labels=labs)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

#### Edit: with an offset

Here it is using the offset to make distance between the bars:

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$hp_fac <- cut(mtcars$hp, breaks=3)
tab <- table(mtcars$hp_fac, mtcars$am)
offset <- 2
nums <- t(apply(tab, 1,rev))
pcts <- prop.table(cbind(0, nums), 1)
pcts <- t(apply(pcts, 1, cumsum))
yvals <- pcts[,-ncol(pcts)] + (pcts[,-1] - pcts[,-ncol(pcts)])/2
xvals <- cumsum(c(0, rowSums(nums)/sum(rowSums(nums))))
xvals <- xvals[-length(xvals)] + (xvals[-1] - xvals[-length(xvals)])/2
xvals <- array(xvals, dim=dim(yvals))
xvals <- c(xvals)
offx <- cumsum(c(0, rep(offset*.01, length(xvals)/2 - 1)))
xvals <- xvals + rep(offx, ncol(tab))
yvals <- c(yvals)
labs <- sprintf("n = %.0f", c(nums))

spineplot(tab,
          col = c("green","blue","orange","purple","yellow"),
          xlab="cluster",
          ylab="DP_measure_quartile",
          off = offset)

text(x=xvals, y=yvals, labels=labs)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works like a charm. One follow-up question: the spineplot function includes an argument "off" that allows one to define an offset between the bars. In my example and the code presented this was set to "0". I have been looking for a while without finding a solution, but would there be a way to make the text labels shift to the right along with this offset value?

Comment: @Tom Apologies for the late reply, but I edited the answer to include an example using the offset.

Comment: Hi @Dave, thank you so much for this. This works perfectly for the mtcars example, but I am struggling to get it to work on my own data. I included a picture of where I am right now in my original question. Do you happen to have any insights on what I might be doing wrong based on this? Happy hollidays btw!

Comment: @Tom: could you put the results of `table(myData$BP_cluster,myData$DP_dispersion_quartile)` in your question.  I think we can sort it out.